# hover highlight over hierarchical divs

Tags: html, css

It is easy to highlight a `div` when mouse hovers on it.

However, when `div`s are inside each other, the parent shades over the rest of the `div`s. How should I tell CSS to hover only on the directly hovered `div`?

When I hover over `parrot`, I don't want `bird` or `animal` to be highlighted.

```css
div.creature{
  margin:5px;
  padding:5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
div.creature:hover{
  background: #ffeeaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="creature">
  animal
  <div class="creature">
    mammal
    <div class="creature">
    cat
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="creature">
    bird
    <div class="creature">
    parrot
    </div>
    <div class="creature">
    duck
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

The HTML code is created dynamically. Hence, an independent CSS is preferred.

When I hover on `bird` but not on `parrot` or `duck`, I expect the entire `bird` highlights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

**Update:** added a jQuery function

```js
$(function() {
    $('div').on('mouseover', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).addClass('my-bg');
    }).on('mouseout', function(e){
        $(this).removeClass('my-bg');
    })
});
```

```css
div.creature{
  margin:5px;
  padding:5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.my-bg{
  background-color: #ffeeaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="creature">
  animal
  <div class="creature">
    mammal
    <div class="creature">
    cat
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="creature">
    bird
    <div class="creature">
    parrot
    </div>
    <div class="creature">
    duck
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. There are two problems. I expect, hovering on `bird` or `mammal` themselves, highlight their entire `div`. The `div`s are also created dynamically. Therefore, I do not know what to write in CSS in advance.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now it's working according to your expectations. An additional jQuery function has been added, so don't forget to include jQuery file in your project.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I add content to a `div` dynamically, do I need to run the jquery code again?

Comment: For your problem, No you don't need to call the script again. Just include it in your project and it will work fine. Kindly accept my answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: I need to call the commands again. Do multiple event calls overwrite or accumulate?

Comment: please update your question with the current code that you have tried.

Comment: Not very optimized method, but still works. https://jsfiddle.net/n5x7j0s8/1/
I will post a good method after a while :)

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as I can get. I used [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

The issue that remains is to turn off the parent background when one of its children is in the `:hover` state which *I don't think* CSS supports since it [doesn't have parent selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

That shouldn't be too difficult to fix with JS

```css
div.fruit {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background:white; /* otherwise the divs have no background */
}

.fruit:hover {
  background: red;  /* Main parent div  */
}

.fruit > div:nth-of-type(1):hover {
  background: blue; /* First child div */
}

.fruit > div:nth-of-type(1):hover > div:nth-of-type(1):hover {
  background: green; /* First grandchild div */
}

.fruit > div:nth-of-type(2):hover {
  background: yellow; /* second child div */
}

.fruit > div:nth-of-type(3):hover {
  background: orange; /* third child div */
}
```

```html
<div class="fruit">A1
  <div class="fruit">AA1
    <div class="fruit">AAA1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fruit">AA2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are doing exactly what you want already. You simply forgot to set a background color on them, so they are showing through to the div beneath. Here is a fiddle demonstrating this:

```
div.creature{
  margin:5px;
  padding:5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #F3F5F6
}
div.creature:hover{
  background: #FFEEAA;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shavedave1/ucvvcrer/1/

Comment: Misread your problem statement -- it looks like you don't actually want parent containers highlighted when you are in the children containers.